# Basic Assumptions about Ring Operations

Tags: ring-theory

I have brief question about ring operations. My textbook poses the problem:

> Verify that $\mathscr{F}$($\Bbb{R}$) (the set of all real functions) satisfies all of the axioms for being a commutative ring with unity. Indicate the zero and the unity, and describe the negative of any $\mathit{f}$.

Since the problem does not specify the operations on $\mathscr{F}$($\Bbb{R}$), should I assume that they are the traditional operations of addition and multiplication on functions?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathscr{F}$($\Bbb{R}$)?

Comment: I'll assume that by $\mathscr{F}(\Bbb R)$ you mean the set of all real functions.  That seems like a safe bet to assume they mean traditional addition and multiplication of functions then.  There are some scenarios where you might opt to use other choices, e.g. composition, but I see that more often for permutations or linear functions rather than the set of all functions.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the notation $\mathscr F(\Bbb R)$.  What does it mean?  All functions  $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$?  If that's the case, then yes, the operations are pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication of functions.

Comment: The set refers to the set of all real functions, yes. I apologize for not clarifying this in my original post. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Correct. If no explicit operations are given, but there is a natural set of operations to consider, then you consider that natural set. We have a standard way of adding and multiplying elements of $\mathscr{F}(\mathbb{R})$ (pointwise), and so since no other operations are mentioned, assume those are the ones at issue.

Comment: I presume OP means ${\mathbb R}^X$ for some fixed set $X$ (the set of functions $X\to\mathbb R$, with pointwise addition/multiplication

Comment: @MPW: Most likely, $X=\mathbb{R}$. In analogy with vector space, were $L(V,W)$ means all linear maps from $V$ to $W$, but $L(V)$ means all linear maps $V$ to $V$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin : That’s reasonable